# he started feeling the place around him?

Tags: meaning, sentence

Am trying to describe a scene:
Imagine someone that falls to the ground when the lights went out... and when he tries to get up I want to say "he started feeling the place around him." 
Is it correct ?

Comment: This looks like "writing advice" to me, but FWIW I'd probably use ***space*** rather than ***place*** - though he'd presumably be "feeling" objects and surfaces, not the (empty) space around them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider ...

**grope in the dark**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/grope)

> 1. Literally, to feel about without the use of one's eyes, as due to blindness or an absence of light.

As in:

> He fell to the ground when the lights went out... and groping in the
>   dark he tries to stand.